# what is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

what is `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` ?

I read from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html) :*Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported* , but couldn't understand what does that mean.

What are the *major and minor versions* in the file ?

I launched an application in someone else machine when the following exception was thrown :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: client (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
```

though it worked fine on my machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different versions of the JDK compiler generate different class versions. For instance, Java 1.4 generates 48.0, 1.5 generates 49.0 and 1.6 50.0.

A JVM is generally able to load classes from JVMs "lesser" than itself but never greater. You are probably trying to use a class compiled for 1.6 on a 1.5 JVM, or the like.

A good tool for finding class versions is [bcel](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) if you are interested. In particular, it has a nice set of ant tasks.

Comment: `javap` (built-in disassembler in java) can be used to check the major and minor version. BCEL would be more appropriate if you want to do this version check programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

That means your compiler version is more recent than the jvm version where you are trying to run the classes. Either downgrade your machine's java compiler or upgrade the other machine's runtime jvm.

Comment: There is a third option (for most java compilers).  You can do something like `javac -target 1.1` which will from a modern compiler produce bytecode suitable for an ancient JVM.  There is no need to actually downgrade the compiler.

Comment: @ emory what does `1.1` denote ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta In my example, I have a 1.7 compiler but I want to use the bytecode on a 1.1 JVM.  More likely in your case, you have a 1.6 compiler but want to use the byte code on a 1.5 JVM (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8605030/348975) - then you would use `javac -target 1.5`

Comment: @ emory I understand know . But i have a java 1.7 compiler. How do you guess which compiler I would have ! ?

Comment: @ emory this was what happened when i tried to convert 1.7 code to 1.6 . `javac: target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.7`